# SQL: Help identifying patterns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, active-directory

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

What I am trying to do is consolidate groups based on the same ResourceName and Permissions and give them the same unique identifier. However I have groups repeating themselves for multiple ResourceNames and cannot give the same group another unique ID.

For instance, GroupAdmin and GroupUser1 will be one set with an ID and GroupUser2 and GroupUser3 would be another set. I have millions of rows like this.

Please help me write a query or some code to figure this out. Thanks!!

**EDIT**added table without picture

```
ResourceName    Permissions        GroupName
Resource1           Modify             GroupAdmin
Resource1           Modify             GroupUser1
Resource1           Read & Execute         GroupUser2
Resource1           Read & Execute         GroupUser3
Resource2           Modify             GroupAdmin
Resource2           Modify             GroupUser1
Resource2           Read & Execute         GroupUser2
Resource2           Read & Execute         GroupUser3
Resource3           Modify             GroupAdmin
Resource3           Modify             GroupUser1
Resource3           Read & Execute         GroupUser2
Resource3           Read & Execute         GroupUser3
Resource4           Modify             GroupAdmin
Resource4           Modify             GroupUser1
Resource4           Read & Execute         GroupUser2
Resource4           Read & Execute         GroupUser3
```

Comment: You should edit your question and put in sample data and desired results.  I for one cannot see the picture you attempted to add.

Answer (score 1):

```
select r + '-' + p as id, r, p, g from rpg;
```

Will provide you a an ID in a very simple way, based on same ResourceName r and Permissions p.

Or you can do this:

```
select r, p, g, rank() over(order by r, p) as id from rpg;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried this and you're right it gives a nice ID output but  it will give a new ID to a group  as soon as the the ResourceName changes. I can't have a group with more than 1 ID...

Comment: So you want this as a frequently running procedure? The task was to identify the pattern with SQL, implying to get the information and a grouping with a new ID at one point of time.
I would suggest to create a new table persisting already "generated" IDs for ResourceName-Permission couples and doing a outer join, only handling the rows which do not match (NULL) to any row in this new table in the way described above.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion, next time it would help to add a table of your desired results. With that being said, I think I figured out what you want.

Try this:

```
--Create A Simple Version of YourTable
SELECT * INTO YourTable
FROM
(
    SELECT 'Resource1' AS ResourceName, 'Modify' AS [Permissions], 'GroupAdmin' AS GroupName
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Resource1', 'Modify', 'GroupUser1'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Resource1', 'Read & Execute', 'GroupUser2'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Resource1', 'Read & Execute', 'GroupUser3'

) A


SELECT  A.ID,
        B.GroupName

FROM
(
    --Groups Resource and Permssion combinations and assigns ID using row_number()
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ResourceName,[Permissions]) ID,
            ResourceName,[Permissions]
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY ResourceName,[Permissions]
) A
--Match up your GroupNames to your Resource/Permssion Pairs
INNER JOIN YourTable B
    ON A.ResourceName = B.ResourceName
    AND A.[Permissions] = B.[Permissions]
```

Results:

```
ID                   GroupName
-------------------- ----------
1                    GroupAdmin
1                    GroupUser1
2                    GroupUser2
2                    GroupUser3
```